# React datetime picker misbehaving

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have following `<Datetime>` picker from [react-datetime](https://github.com/arqex/react-datetime) library.

```
import React from "react";
import Datetime from "react-datetime";
import moment from "moment";

import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fromDateTime: "",
    };
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Datetime
          value={this.state.fromDateTime}
          dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          onChange={(momentObj) => {
            if (momentObj && momentObj.isValid && momentObj.isValid()) {
              const formattedDateTime = momentObj.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
              this.setState({ fromDateTime: formattedDateTime });
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I can copy pasted date `2023-06-15 00:30` into the input field. But once I copy pasted, I cannot use delete and backspace button to modify that date. Why is it so?

You can try out this behavior in [https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-tereshkova-h7pmjc?file=/src/App.jsthis codesandbox].

PS: In codesandbox, the calendar is always open. This is not the case on my laptop. Calendar opens when I click inside input box and closes when I click outside.

Answer (score 1):

Once, if you click the date on calendar, it returns value which is no longer date like 2021-06-15 00:0.

So, change the non-date values ​​to be updatable. like :

```
if (momentObj && momentObj.isValid && momentObj.isValid()) {
          const formattedDateTime = momentObj.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
          this.setState({ fromDateTime: formattedDateTime });
        } else {
          this.setState({ fromDateTime: momentObj.toString() });
        }
```